# Problemas para desserializar array aninhado

Tags: java, json

Estou com problemas para desserializar o trecho JSON  abaixo, especificamente a tag "body_text". Isolando esta tag, o código funciona perfeitamente.

O conceito seria uma lista dentro de outra lista? Fiquei confuso!

```js
{
    "type": "BODY",
    "text": "Olá seja bem-vindo {{1}}, continue navegando!",
    "example": {
        "body_text": [["Test","Test_2"]]
    }
}
```

Já tentei desserializar com `List`, `HashMap` e `String`. O DTO está assim:

```
public class ExampleDto {

    @JsonProperty("body_text")
    private List<String> bodyText;

    @JsonProperty("header_handle")
    private List <String> headerHandle;

}
```

O erro retornado é esse:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: O seu `private List<String> bodyText;` pede uma lista de strings, mas no seu array é uma listra dentro de outra lista: `"body_text": [["Test","Test_2"]]`, é um array-multidimensional, para funcionar com o `List<String>` provavelmente deveria ser `"body_text": ["Test","Test_2"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [sintaxe do formato JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), um array é delimitado por colchetes, e seus elementos são separados por vírgula. Mas caso haja somente um elemento, não há vírgula. Ou seja, `[1]` é um array que contém apenas um elemento (o número `1`), e `[1, 2]` é um array que contém dois elementos (os números `1` e `2`).

Mas nada impede que um array esteja dentro de outro. No seu caso, temos um array que contém apenas um elemento. E esse elemento é **outro** array, que contém dois elementos (as strings `"Test"` e `"Test_2"`).

```
início do primeiro array         fim do primeiro array
↓                                ↓
[  [    "Test" , "Test_2"     ]  ]
   ↑                          ↑
   início do segundo array    fim do segundo array
```

Ou seja, `bodyText` não é uma lista de string, e sim uma lista de lista de string:

```
@JsonProperty("body_text")
private List<List<String>> bodyText;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. A implementação funcionou perfeitamente. Abs

Comment: Novamente agradeço, desconhecia esse processo! Abs